# PHP Get keys with values from object

Tags: php, object

I am using `simplexml_load_string()` in PHP to parse my XML File.
Now, for better reading, I `json_encode()`d my object:
http://pastebin.com/Hk8YCssR (Example Representation Plan of a german School)
I want one object with all actions in it and one with all keys of the "head".
I tried to loop through these keys, but I wasn't abled to get the value of a keys key, e.g.:

```
"action":[  
     {  
        "class":"5/2",
        "period":"5",
        ...
```

In this case, to get the value "5/2".

I don't have the exact code, but I am writing in sketch what I've done:

```
$value = current((array)$xml);
echo $value;

foreach ($xml as $key) {
  // echo $key[];
}
```

---

P.S.: Thank you for reading this

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: It is hard to help unless you show us what you have exactly tried.

Comment: Otherwise you are just requesting to get solution without even trying .

Comment: `array_keys($xml['head']))`

Comment: @Barmar I get this error: PHP Warning array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: If it's an object, not an array, it should be `$xml->head`.

Comment: `get_object_vars($xml->head)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sv_infch=get_object_vars($xml[0]->info);
foreach($sv_infch as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
    echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
    print_r($sv_infch);
}
```